# Maximal Latin Rectangle not Containing Latin Rectangles

Tags: combinatorics, extremal-combinatorics

**Problem :**

I am looking to construct maximal latin rectangles $r\times n$ that do not contain smaller latin rectangles.

More formally, for any two rows $\{p_1,...,p_n\}$ and $\{q_1,...,q_n\}$, I want to have :

For all non-empty $C\subset \{1,...,n\}$, $\bigcup_{i\in C}\{p_i\}\neq \bigcup_{i\in C}\{q_i\}$

**Example :**

\begin{array}{c c c c c c}
1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6\\
6 & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5
\end{array}

works whereas

\begin{array}{c c c c c c}
1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6\\
6 & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5\\
5 & 6 & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4
\end{array}

does not work as both the first and third rows have $\{1,3,5\}$ on columns 1, 3 and 5 and $\{2,4,6\}$ on columns 2, 4 and 6.

**Questions :**

- Is there a name for these sorts of things so that I can look them up myself ? Some kind of generalization of derangements maybe ?
- Is there any known results on the maximal number of rows these rectangles can have for a given n ?
- In the case the answer to the previous question is positive, is there any algorithm for constructing them ?

Thanks in advance,

Authary